# react native items not align vertically center

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to center the items of flatlist using alignItems but none of justifyContent, alignItems is working on this

```js
<View style={styles.citiesContainer}>
                    <FlatList
                        data={cities}
                        renderItem={renderItem}
                        keyExtractor={item => item}
                        horizontal={true}
                    />
                </View>
                
// styling part
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
citiesContainer: {
        height: 110,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
  }
```

Check those black circles in the red box in the image, I want to vertically center those circles (items)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#columnwrapperstyle

```
                    <FlatList
                        columnWrapperStyle={styles.citiesContainer}}
                        data={cities}
                        renderItem={renderItem}
                        keyExtractor={item => item}
                        horizontal={true}
                    />
```

Answer (score 0):

change the flex direction will do, try `flexDirection : 'row'`

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
citiesContainer: {
        height: 110,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: '100%',
        flexDirection : 'row', //this right here!! :)
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hopeful this might work,